# About PHP header for redirection, browser aborts it in below case

Tags: php, ajax

I have a function, in which we do request to a service(a php file) using ajax call. In which I have PHP function which read data From DB and send that back, in case of failure while getting the data I do redirect using header to the error file.

On my local machine all works fine even with http/https request. But on a specific sever which has all same configuration settings as my local one, it header request is "Aborted" and redirection fails.

I would like to know what things might lead to such situation.

Ajax Call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getdataForUser.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'User' : userName
            },
    dataType: 'html',                         
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);                                                      
     },
    error : function() {
        console.log('call error .');

    }
});
```

PHP Function : getdataForUser.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        $transaction = array('User' => $_POST['User']
                         );
    }
    $result = $client->__soapCall("GetUserDetails",array($transaction));
    if($result == FALSE)
    {
        header( 'Location: error.php' ); // THIS REDIRECTION IS BEING ABORTED
        die();
    }
    print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: can't help you without seeing some code

Comment: A redirect header in an ajax call? is this supposed to work? oO

Comment: Atleast show us some code to see what you have done

Comment: Aborted is usually the local browser cancelling an HTTP operation (like stop asking for an image because the SRC attribute changed).  Without knowing what your service is or how it is being called, we can't really offer much more.

Comment: Updated code snippet. Please have a look. All suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Hi emma, check whether you have any JS error, as in the above code the line "console.lof(data);" will throw an error. It should be "console.log"

Comment: @VinodkumarSaravana : I have corrected that, no errors on console.

Comment: @Emma - try to give full URL at "url: 'getdataForUser.php'," instead of filename alone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ajax, you must handle response from server in js, ajax not accept header from server;

For example
JS:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'getdataForUser.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'User' : userName
            },
    dataType: 'JSON',                         
    success: function (data) {
      if(data.status == 'error'){
        window.location.href = data.url;
      }                                    
     },
    error : function() {
        console.log('call error .');

    }
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
   if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') === 'xmlhttprequest') {  
     echo  json_encode(array('status'=>'error','url'=>'http://example.com'));
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it works fine on my local machine. Why does the behavior changes? What things to be considered? Cause firstly I felt like is a certificate issue. But its not when I dig deep into the issue.

Comment: no idea why it works on your local machine but the above is correct.  You have to pass the url back with a flag of success or fail or error and then do the redirect in javascript.  Because the end browser client never actually sees the page being called by the ajax then the redirect is never hitting the client browser.

Comment: Ok. I'll try the same. n will get back to you! :) Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Cannot help you much without looking at the code. Try the mentioned below:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'window.location.href="'.$page.'";';
echo '</script>';
```

**And remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.**